# Using scrapy with scrapyd in Django not entering def(parse)

Tags: python, django, scrapy, scrapyd

i'm still learning scrapy and i am trying to use scrapy with scrapyd inside a Django Project.

But i am noticing that the spider just wont enter the def(parse)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class NewsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    print("Start SPIDER")
    name = 'detik'
    allowed_domains = ['news.detik.com']
    start_urls = ['https://news.detik.com/indeks/all/?date=02/28/2018']

def parse(self, response):
    print("SEARCH LINK")
    urls = response.xpath("//article/div/a/@href").extract()        
    for url in urls:
        url = response.urljoin(url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_detail)

def parse_detail(self,response):
    print("SCRAPEEE")
    x = {}
    x['breadcrumbs'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='breadcrumb']/a/text()").extract()
    x['tanggal'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='date']/text()").extract_first()
    x['penulis'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='author']/text()").extract_first()
    x['judul'] = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract_first()
    x['berita'] = response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='detail_text'])").extract_first()
    x['tag'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='detail_tag']/a/text()").extract()
    x['url'] = response.request.url
    return x
```

The print("Start Spider") is in the log but the print("Search Link") is not.

i also have this kind of error

```
  [Launcher,3804/stderr] Unhandled error in Deferred:
```

Please help.
PS : When i run it outside the Django it work just fine

Thank you

Comment: try this tutorial maybe it will help https://medium.com/@ali_oguzhan/how-to-use-scrapy-with-django-application-c16fabd0e62e

Comment: i actually TRY the tutorial. and it's work, but when i changed it into my own spider. it's just won't work (the tutorial doesn't need parse)

Comment: Do you see the request going to https://news.detik.com/indeks/all/?date=02/28/2018 in terminal?

Comment: Yes, i added print after the start_urls and it's work. i think the Unhandled error in Deferred is more the problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are missing the crawling rules in your spider.

Try adding

```
KwSpiderSpider.rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=".+", unique=True),callback='parse'),
]
```

to your code, after the `start_urls`.
I don't understand how it could work outside of django though.

Comment: Hello. it's seems that the problem is in pipeline not the spider. i already solved it. but i don't know how to close this thread. the spider work just fine